# Can't assign value to variable in ngOnInit()

Tags: angular, typescript

I do the call to api in *ngOnInit()* and I want to do some more things on data from api in *ngOnInit()*.

But when I try to *console.log()* my data I got undefined and can not process more. When I *console.log()* the same data in *getUsers()* method when I subscribe data from service I have my array with json data.
Api response:

`{"items":[{"id":"1","name":"Adam","age":20},{"id":"2","name":"Cris","age":32}]}`

UserResults is my whole JSON. And I need only users in my users Array not item.

service.ts

```
public getUsers(): Observable<UserResults> {
    return this.httpClient.get<UserResults>(baseURL);
  }
```

component.ts

```
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  usersResult: UserResults;
  users: Users[];


  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUsers();
    // shouldn't be users array available ???
    console.log(this.getUsers()) // undefined
    ///more calculations
  }

  private getUsers() {
    this.dataService.getUsers().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.users = data.items;
    console.log(this.getUsers()) // correct data in json array
      }
    )
  }
}
```

How should I handle it the best way?

Comment: may i know why you want data on ngOninit?

Comment: I need data when I enter my website And I do first api call there and I need do some manipulation on data too. Should I use other hook?

Comment: you could make use of behaviour subject in your service.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to `console.log` your method, which returns nothing and is asynchronous, rather than the data returned.

If you really need the data within the `ngOnInit`, you need to subscribe to your Observable in there, and not in a separate private method.

Note that this is not generally the best way to handle data returning from an HTTP request. Depending on how the data is consumed, you would generally want to create the Observable in your TypeScript code, and subscribe to it in the template with the `async` pipe wherever possible. For example:

component.ts:

```js
this.users$ = this.dataService.getUsers().pipe(
  map(data => data.items) // this is now an Observable<User[]>
);
```

component.html:

```html
<div class="user-pane" *ngFor="let user of (users$ | async)">
```

Don't forget that asynchronous stuff takes time. You can't call an asynchronous method in one line and then consume the results in the following line.